# Setting up multiple SSL certificate. Certificate and Private Key don't match

Tags: apache2, ssl

I'm trying to set up multiple SSL certificates on my Ubuntu VPS running apache.  Before I only had one certificate for one domain but now I want to set up a certificate for another domain.

I bought an SSL certificate and I was sent a .crt file which I uploaded to `/etc/apache2/ssl/www_domain_com/domain.crt`.  In my virtual host config I have the following two lines

```
SSLCertificateFile     /etc/apache2/ssl/www_domain_com/www_domain_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/www_domain_com/server.key
```

This is working at the moment because my apache error log says the two don't match but I don't understand what the server.key file needs to contain?  Should I have been sent this when I bought the SSL certificate?

I have a server.key file for the other domain which I've successfully set up a certificate for, do I need to use that file?

Would someone be able to explain the purpose of this file and how I need to generate it.

Comment: Before you request a CSR, you will create a KEY on the server.  That is the KEY you will be loading, with your .CRT that is given by the signer.  If you used an existing key, then yes, you would use that key.

Comment: @bc2946088 I created a key by using the following command `sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/www_domain_com/server.key` is something like that correct?

Comment: Yes that would work and be your key for apache.  Are you sure you have a properly matching `Common Name` to your apache sitename?

Answer (score 1):

Answering all your questions (for anyone that stumbles across this in the future):

> This is working at the moment because my apache error log says the two don't match but I don't understand what the server.key file needs to contain?

It needs to contain a private key.

> Should I have been sent this when I bought the SSL certificate?

Not typically.  When you purchase a TLS certificate from a public Certificate Authority (CA), you provide a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) and they provide a corresponding signed certificate, along with the certificate chain linking back to their trusted root certificate.  The CSR is created from a private key that you generate locally.  (Note: the `req -x509` command you mention in your comment will generate a self-signed cert, not a CSR.)

> I have a server.key file for the other domain which I've successfully set up a certificate for, do I need to use that file?

Assuming you want to host both domains: yes.  Setting up a single Apache instance to serve up multiple secure domains requires the use of Server Name Indication (SNI), a TLS extension.  You must configure Apache separately for each domain you wish to host.  See the Apache `VirtualHost` directive for details.

> Would someone be able to explain the purpose of this file and how I need to generate it.

The process for creating a CSR involves first creating a private key.  You should have already completed this step before you sent the CSR to the CA.  There are some sites that can generate the key and CSR in the browser when you purchase your certificate; in this case you will be prompted by your browser to save the private key to disk.

Aside: You should protect your private keys: make sure they are only readable by the system administrator / web server.